# Modify argument in batch script

Tags: sql, batch-file, powershell, vbscript, wsh

In a nutshell basically what we need is a way to convert a batch file containing this content -> **sqlcmd -S rave -v Your payment is late = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt**

-to-

A new batch file containing this content -> **sqlcmd -S rave -v "'Your payment is late'" = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt**

Comment: You want it both double and single quoted? And the `old_batchfile.bat` is generating `new_batchfile.bat` ? Should it be literal `%1` or the value of argument? As in: if `%1` is *"foo"* you want `"'themessage = foo'"` ?

Comment: Click [edit] below question to update.

Comment: I have added some information to help clarify the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL? SQLCMD is a Microsoft tool and the syntax should be `-v var = "string with spaces"`. This being the case, the you should be able to achieve the same result by "en-quoting" the parameter that is sent to old_batchfile.bat. e.g. `old_batchfile.bat "this is the message"`. This should result in a command line of `sqlcmd -S rave -v themessage = "this is the message" -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt`

Comment: There is inconsistency in your two explanations. In the first one you quote *`themessage = %1`* in the second you only quote *`themessage`* and not `%1`. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: You are correct in that it is Microsoft SQL and not MySQL. In a nutshell basically what we need is a way to convert a batch file containing this content -> sqlcmd -S rave -v Your payment is late = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt to a new batch file containing this content -> sqlcmd -S rave -v "'Your payment is late'" = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear to me. Do you want to create a new batch file based on the content of the old one? If so, I'd recommend using PowerShell for the transformation:

```
$srch = '-v\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*%1'
$repl = "-v `"'`$1'`" = %1"

(Get-Content old.bat) -replace $srch, $repl | Set-Content new.bat
```

Comment: I have added some information to help clarify the issue.

Comment: Yes. I believe in effect that is what we want to do. Create a new batch file based on the content of the old one.

Comment: In a nutshell basically what we need is a way to convert a batch file containing this content -> sqlcmd -S rave -v Your payment is late = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt

-to-

A new batch file containing this content -> sqlcmd -S rave -v "'Your payment is late'" = %1 -i rave_params.sql -o alert.txt

Comment: I tried this powershell script. It looks as though it will accomplish what we need. Will it generate the new batch file or do I need to have one in place already? Thanks. I ran the script on the old  bat and it did not update the new bat. Am I missing something?

Comment: @woodlawn_la: You can copy/paste the code from my answer into a PowerShell console window. It will read a file `old.bat` from the current working directory and create an output file `new.bat` in the same directory. An existing file `new.bat` will be overwritten.